# Kiss fft linker error in Borland C++

Tags: c++, signal-processing, borland-c++, kissfft

I have a problem with compiling my program. I am using Kiss FFT library in my project but when i'm trying to build it I get those errors:

```
[Linker Error] Error: Unresolved external '_kiss_fft_alloc' referenced from C:\[path]\UNIT4.OBJ

[Linker Error] Error: Unresolved external '_kiss_fft' referenced from C:\[path]\UNIT4.OBJ
```

I assume it's something about '_' before name of function but I have no idea how to solve it so far.

Code:

Unit4.cpp - gist.github.com/anonymous/fa33e0982240b00ff8c8

Unit4.h - gist.github.com/anonymous/b35e9abf93c93aeb1d45

[EDIT]

I switched to FFWT library but I have the same issue. I have compiled libraries and added them to Borland project in compilator path and linker path.

```
[Linker Error] Error: Unresolved external '_fftw_malloc' referenced from C:\[path]\UNIT4.OBJ
[Linker Error] Error: Unresolved external '_fftw_plan_dft_1d' referenced from C:\[path]\UNIT4.OBJ
[Linker Error] Error: Unresolved external '_fftw_execute' referenced from C:\[path]\UNIT4.OBJ
[Linker Error] Error: Unresolved external '_fftw_destroy_plan' referenced from C:\[path]\UNIT4.OBJ
[Linker Error] Error: Unresolved external '_fftw_free' referenced from C:\[path]\UNIT4.OBJ
```

For example when i use

Comment: Have you definitely added the library to your project? Is the problem with **your** project failing to build or the external library?

Comment: Unit4.cpp - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fa33e0982240b00ff8c8
Unit4.h - https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b35e9abf93c93aeb1d45

Yes, i have added directory with Kiss FFT to compilator and linker path and i have see kiss Fft functions in intelisence so somewhat it's working.

Sorry if my code is a little clumsy, i'm trying many things right now.

Comment: But i'm adding just kiss_fft.h... maybe that is not right way but i hadn't found any information about usage of it so far so i assume it worked that way. Maybe thats the problem.

Comment: given you have added the .lib to the project, have you regenerated the .lib itself using  Borland implib tools ? start from this link to get more info on how-to  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f3e4fb2e-1f9d-4e95-aebd-8f1523f60ed2/problem-in-linking-the-vc-library-with-borland-c?forum=vcgeneral

Comment: No, i have used kiss_fft
.h file. There is no .lib. 
Thank you for link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is  basic C/C++ usage.

You must include the compiled code in your project for it to be used in your project.

KISSFFT comes with the source.  That source must be compiled and linked to your program.

FFTW is installed in the form of a library. Someone else compiled it into libraries. You are linking it into your executable with "#pragma comment(lib ..."

Answer (score 1):

I have found solution for FFTW library in Borland. Beside compilation of lib files by 'implib' i added

```
#pragma comment(lib, "fftw3-3.lib")
#pragma comment(lib, "fftw3f-3.lib" )
#pragma comment(lib, "fftw3l-3.lib" )
```

Also copied .dll files to executable folder and it compiles now. Yet, I am not sure if it's working properly.

Kiss FFT is still mistery for me.